# I am using Linux kernel 4.8 but still getting 4.4 updates

Tags: release-loki, kernel

I am using elementaryOS Loki. I have installed 4.8 from Ubuntu repository.  But I am still getting 4.4 updates. I don't need 4.4 any more since my computer is working just fine on 4.8. How can make 4.4 from appearing in update list.
P.S: I know about package blacklist by apt, but I was hoping for different solution.
Thanks

Comment: I guess you have still a 4.4 kernel installed. What is the output of `dpkg -l |grep linux-image` (in a terminal window)?

Comment: @lemonslice http://sprunge.us/JjDU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove all Linux 4.4 kernels via:

```
sudo apt remove --purge linux-image-4.4.*
```

However you might want to keep always at least two kernel versions (the running one and a backup in case an upgrade goes wrong).

Comment: I have removed 4.4. Your code needs an edit, `4.4.*` must be between single qoutes